# How to pass a instance/accessor variable in ruby to another class and get data stored in respective variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Referring to the below code is there a way that I can pass the variable `row` from `class A`  to `class B#kick` and get the data stored?

```
class A
  attr_accessor :row

  def fetch
    B.new.kick(self.row)
    puts row.inspect
  end
end

class B
  def kick(x)
    x = [3,4]
  end
end

@test = A.new.fetch
expect(@test.row).to eql([3,4])
```

Current O/P `=> nil`

However If I pass self and assign that works , but I dont want to use this approach:
Working Code

```
class A
  attr_accessor :row

  def fetch
    B.new.kick(self)
    puts row.inspect
  end
end

class B
  def kick(x)
    x.row = [3,4]
  end
end

@test = A.new.fetch
#=> [3, 4]
```

Comment: This is expected because case 1 is a value and case 2 is a reference. You can only access object methods by referencing the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version:
`x = [3, 4]` will create new instance of array and saves to `x` variable, where `row` will still reference to the original value(or no value `nil`).

Another approach could be the `kick` method to return "kicked" value.

```
class A
  def fetch
    @row = B.new.kick
    puts row.inspect
  end
end

class B
  def kick(x)
    [3,4]
  end
end
```

If you want to follow object-oriented programming principle "Tell, don't ask" you can try visitor pattern approach.

```
class A
  def fetch
    B.new.kick(self)
    puts row.inspect
  end

  def save(row)
    @row = row
  end
end

class B
  def kick(x)
    x.save([3,4])
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, this works fine 

but my use case is something like what if `B.new.kick` raises an error I will not get any data.

My use case is I want to store the data in array in runtime even if kick method raises an exception I have data in it.

Comment: @SantoshMohanty, you will not get any data anyway if error will be raised in a `kick` method.

Comment: @SantoshMohanty: if your version of `B#kick` raises an error, the program will crash just as well.